# How to trim allocated space

Tags: data-recovery

I used ddrescue and Photorec to help a friend recover files from a dying 1TB Seagate HD from a Windows 10 machine.

I created an img file with ddrescue, and ran Photorec against that img file. I saved the recovered files from Photrec to a drive on my Linux system.

Krusader reported the total size of files recovered was:

```
217.7 GiB (233,703,139,398)
1,183,509 files, 2,403 sub-folders
```

With this info I had my friend order a size appropriate drive to transfer the files back. I was given a 500GB Sandisk SSD.

So I used rsync to copy these files onto the SSD, but to my surprise, I quickly ran out of space. I removed a lot of the big files like `image_remaining.dd` which was 142.5GB itself, but I still ran out of space.

It took me a while to figure out what was happening, but after having a look using qdirstat, I see that there is an enormous amount of allocated space.

What would be the best strategy for getting the recovered files to fit onto the SSD?
Is it even possible?

[image]

- Windows Drive: `ntfs`
- Linux Drive: `ext4`
- SSD Drive: `exfat`

Comment: ddrescue does not recover files? Tell us complete story. Did you use PhotoRec perhaps?

Comment: also, if you're using exfat with huge clustersize this is to be expected. even smallest files needs an entire cluster allocated to it.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, my apologies. I've edited the question to include more details, and the use of Photorec. Are you saying that if I formatted the SSD to ntfs it would fit?

Comment: Much slower, but does not preallocate and waste space: just copy all *files and folders* from one partition to another. Of course, it also depends on how file size is measured -- space on a drive also includes all of the last partial allocation unit, so ~1.2 million files will take up more space on the drive than one might think. I.E., a one byte file takes up one whole allocation unit.

Comment: Do you maybe have any large sparse files?

Comment: @DanielB, not sure. There were over 1 million files, but only 20+ over 1GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint by @JoepvanSteen, I was able to make everything fit easily by formatting the drive to NTFS. I was able to add all of the large files back, including the single 142.5GB file.

I wasn't familiar with the large cluster size of exfat, and was only using the file system that came on the drive. I'll understand this limitation in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For file recovery I'd recommend a file recovery tool that relies on the file system rather than a carver or raw scanner like PhotoRec. DMDE is an example of a tool that can parse or analyse and reconstruct a virtual file system.

A carver or raw scanner:

- Will have more trouble determining correct file sizes - too small but also inflated sizes.
- Almost by definition will produce false positives.

A file system based tool:

- Gets correct file sizes if file is detected by file system meta data.
- Gives a folder/file list which makes file selection easier.

And as I already mentioned in comments, check the exFAT cluster size of the drive you copy to as for even the smallest file, an entire cluster needs to be allocated. So even 1.000.000, 1 KB files (about 1 GB) will mean 1.000.000 * 128K will be allocated with 128K clusters (about 130 GB).